# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException error when injecting bytecode using ASM

Tags: java, bytecode

Good morning,
I'm trying to inject this code:

```
int i = getKey();
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
System.out.println(timeStamp + " " + i);
```

inside an existing method using *ASM library*.

So I tried to run this code inside a very basic class inside the tool: ASMifier. After that, I copied the part of the output I'm interested in.

```
mv.visitTypeInsn(NEW, "java/text/SimpleDateFormat");
mv.visitInsn(DUP);
mv.visitLdcInsn("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss");
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "java/text/SimpleDateFormat", "", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
mv.visitTypeInsn(NEW, "java/util/Date");
mv.visitInsn(DUP);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "java/util/Date", "", "()V", false);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/text/SimpleDateFormat", "format", "(Ljava/util/Date;)Ljava/lang/String;", false);
mv.visitVarInsn(ASTORE, 3);
mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
mv.visitTypeInsn(NEW, "java/lang/StringBuilder");
mv.visitInsn(DUP);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "java/lang/StringBuilder", "", "()V", false);
mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 3);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/StringBuilder", "append", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;", false);
mv.visitLdcInsn(" ");
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/StringBuilder", "append", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;", false);
mv.visitVarInsn(ILOAD, 2);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/StringBuilder", "append", "(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;", false);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/StringBuilder", "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;", false);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
```

But then I got an error

```
*Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
```

at compile time on the line:

```
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "java/text/SimpleDateFormat", "", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
```

Why did I get this error?

Stack-trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitMethodInsn(Unknown Source)
    at MethodAdapter.visitMethodInsn(MethodAdapter.java:33)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace ?

Comment: Sure, I added it in the question.

Comment: I’m very sure that `ASMifier` doesn’t generate invocation instructions with empty names. So how could these get into your code? Did you copy and paste the code into a web browser that confused `<init>` with HTML tags?

Comment: Maybe this could be the problem; I'm using a web application https://asmifier.herokuapp.com/ instead of the java tool. I'll try with this fix as soon as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it’s the website. It fails even with the most trivial example. But if you let your browser display the HTML code, you’ll see the correct Java code.

Comment: It is working, thank you! :) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the method's name is empty.

If you try to invoke a constructor set the method name as `"<init>"`